# NHibernate extension for querying non mapped property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, extension-methods, projection, queryover

I'm looking for a way to get total price count from the Costs list in my object. I can't get Projections.Sum to work in my QueryOver so I tried another way but I'm having problems with it. I want to use a unmapped property in my QueryOver. I found this example but it's giving an error.

**Object:**

```
public class Participant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double TotalPersonalCosts { get { return Costs.Where(x => x.Code.Equals("Persoonlijk") && x.CostApprovalStatus == CostApprovalStatus.AdministratorApproved).Sum(x => x.Price.Amount); } }
    public IList<Cost> Costs { get; set; }
}
```

The property TotalPersonalCosts is not mapped and contains the total price count.

**Extension Class:**

```
public static class ParticipantExtensions
{
    private static string BuildPropertyName(string alias, string property)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(alias))
        {
            return string.Format("{0}.{1}", alias, property);
        }

        return property;
    }

    public static IProjection ProcessTotalPersonalCosts(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr)
    {
        Expression<Func<Participant, double>> w = r => r.TotalPersonalCosts;

        string aliasName = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(expr);
        string totalPersonalCostName = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(w.Body);

        PropertyProjection totalPersonalCostProjection =
            Projections.Property(BuildPropertyName(aliasName, totalPersonalCostName));

        return totalPersonalCostProjection;
    }
}
```

**My QueryOver:**

```
public override PagedList<AccountantViewInfo> Execute()
    {
       ExpressionProcessor.RegisterCustomProjection(
            () => default(Participant).TotalPersonalCosts,
            expr => ParticipantExtensions.ProcessTotalPersonalCosts(expr.Expression));

        AccountantViewInfo infoLine = null;
        Trip tr = null;
        Participant pa = null;
        Cost c = null;
        Price p = null;

        var infoLines = Session.QueryOver(() => tr)
            .JoinAlias(() => tr.Participants, () => pa);

        if (_status == 0)
            infoLines.Where(() => pa.TotalCostApprovalStatus == TotalCostApprovalStatus.CostPrinted || pa.TotalCostApprovalStatus == TotalCostApprovalStatus.CostPaid);
        else if (_status == 1)
            infoLines.Where(() => pa.TotalCostApprovalStatus == TotalCostApprovalStatus.CostPrinted);
        else
            infoLines.Where(() => pa.TotalCostApprovalStatus == TotalCostApprovalStatus.CostPaid);

        infoLines.WhereRestrictionOn(() => pa.Employee.Id).IsIn(_employeeIds)
                .Select(
                    Projections.Property("pa.Id").WithAlias(() => infoLine.Id),
                    Projections.Property("pa.Employee").WithAlias(() => infoLine.Employee),
                    Projections.Property("pa.ProjectCode").WithAlias(() => infoLine.ProjectCode),
                    Projections.Property("tr.Id").WithAlias(() => infoLine.TripId),
                    Projections.Property("tr.Destination").WithAlias(() => infoLine.Destination),
                    Projections.Property("tr.Period").WithAlias(() => infoLine.Period),
                    Projections.Property("pa.TotalPersonalCosts").WithAlias(() => infoLine.Period)
                );

        infoLines.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<AccountantViewInfo>());

        var count = infoLines.List<AccountantViewInfo>().Count();
        var items = infoLines.List<AccountantViewInfo>().ToList().Skip((_myPage - 1) * _itemsPerPage).Take(_itemsPerPage).Distinct();

        return new PagedList<AccountantViewInfo>
        {
            Items = items.ToList(),
            Page = _myPage,
            ResultsPerPage = _itemsPerPage,
            TotalResults = count,
        };
    }
```

Here the .Expression property is not found from expr.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help or alternatives would be much appreciated!

**Solution with Projection.Sum() thx to xanatos**

```
.Select(
                    Projections.Group(() => pa.Id).WithAlias(() => infoLine.Id),
                    Projections.Group(() => pa.Employee).WithAlias(() => infoLine.Employee),
                    Projections.Group(() => pa.ProjectCode).WithAlias(() => infoLine.ProjectCode),
                    Projections.Group(() => tr.Id).WithAlias(() => infoLine.TripId),
                    Projections.Group(() => tr.Destination).WithAlias(() => infoLine.Destination),
                    Projections.Group(() => tr.Period).WithAlias(() => infoLine.Period),
                    Projections.Sum(() => c.Price.Amount).WithAlias(() => infoLine.TotalPersonalCost)
                );
```

Comment: What problem do you have with `Projections.Sum`? Have you opened a question on it?

Comment: Non connected to your question, `Projections.Property` has an overload you can use like `Projections.Property(() => pa.Id)`

Comment: I don't have a question for it because I kinda gave up on it. But the problem was this "Column "' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." And yes I know about the overload I use them both.

Comment: it's normally quite easy to make a subquery of the sum: `var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Cost>(() => co).Where(() => co.ParticipantId == pa.Id && co.Code == "Persoonlijk").Select(Projections.Sum(() => co.Amount)); var proj = Projections.SubQuery(subquery);` This (`proj`) is the projection... You should be able to put it in the `.Select()`. You will need to change the `Amount.Price` part, because it isn't clear if they are two tables or you simply grouped some columns together.

Comment: I will try that in a minute! I am experimenting with mapped formula fields now.

Comment: I can't use this subquery because I don't have a model reference from Cost to Participant.

Comment: You don't need a model reference from Cost to Participant. It's a Subquery, not a Join! Clearly there must be some fields that let you "connect" the tables :-)

Comment: But I don't have a property in Cost that refers to its parent (Participant). Thats what I need no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72035/discussion-between-xanatos-and-nanou-ponette).

Comment: @NanouPonette, maybe check this Andrew answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28686781/1679310. And I am sure that if he help him to focus on this Question, he will try to help you...

Comment: Hey--I've been busy lately but I'm planning to take a look at this one. Sorry for the delay

Comment: No problem, I got time.

Comment: @NanouPonette: xanatos' answer is correct. You need to return a projection from your extension method that generates the SQL necessary to perform the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use unmapped columns as projection columns of a NHibernate query.

And the way you are trying to do it is conceptually wrong: the `ParticipantExtensions` methods will be called BEFORE executing the query to the server, and their purpose is to modify the SQL query that will be executed. An `IProjection` (the "thing" that is returned by `ProcessTotalPersonaCosts`) is a something that will be put between the SELECT and the FROM in the query. The `TotalCosts` can't be returned by the SQL server because the SQL doesn't know about `TotalCosts`

Comment: I was following this example : http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2015/01/28/queryover-series-part-9-extending-queryover-using-custom-methods-and-properties/ Clearly I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @NanouPonette Read better the example given: he is "rebuilding" the operation server side. He is doing the multiplication in SQL code: `Projections.SqlFunction(multiplication, NHibernateUtil.Double, widthProjection, hProjection)`. The same thing I said: use a Subquery to "emulate" the math operations you would do client-side